# Understanding of returned value of getLocation() Selenium WebDriver API

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium WebDriver APIs, there is a method `getLocation()` which returns point, containing location of top left hand corner of the element. Let's say, it returns `(x, y)`.

Is the point `(x, y)` with respective to Desktop's(browser's when it's in full screen mode) screen resolution or viewport's(The viewport, the visible area of the webpage within the browser window) resolution?

**EDIT**

Based on my answer to this question, I can guess `getLocation()` returns point with respective desktop's screen resolution or entire browser's(including toolbar, searchbar etc.) rather than viewport's. I just want to make sure that if my thinking is correct and if yes, why `getLocation()`'s behaviour is made like that? Is there any Selenium WebDriver method, which will return me point of element with respective to viewport?

Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, initially I had thought the same but when I tried it practically, I found it something different. Please see my answer and edited question.

Comment: I've just found that, at least for ChromeDriver, it's the documentElement, not the viewPort. If you have a position: fixed element and you scroll down the page, the elements getLocation.getY() increases, even though it hasn't moved relative to the viewport. Which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 2):

The "exact place" on the page regardless of visibility.

This is why when doing image cropping if the element doesn't match the whole screen it will try to crop outside the screenshot as the actual element size/position extends beyond the visible screen.

However, if you are looking for the actual page properties and comparing this to the element size based on the location you can determine if a scrollbar should be present or not.  `element` in the example below is an implementation of `IWebElement` as well as `ICoordinates` as the single `IWebElement` would not provide you with the `ICoordinates` interface as utilized below.

```
    Point p = element.LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView;
    OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Internal.ICoordinates p2 = element.Coordinates;
```

The above two offer a slight difference in capturing the location.  The LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView one includes scrolling to the element and then would return the location based on the top left corner of the screen.

The Coordinates gives the specific location in various ways and includes the `LocationInViewport` property which would provide what you are looking for I believe.

```
    p = p2.LocationInViewport;
    p = p2.LocationOnScreen;
    p = p2.LocationInDom;
    object obj = p2.AuxiliaryLocator;
```

Comment: Yes, initially I had thought the same but when I tried it practically, I found it something different. Please see my answer and edited question.

Comment: Sorry, yes I contradicted myself in my answer as well...location of element even if that is off page.  I'll edit my answer...

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, it returns the point with respective Desktop's screen resolution or entire browser's(including toolbar, searchbar etc.), not viewpoint's.

Here is what I tried. In following code, I'm getting source element's location(which is point (x,y) of top left corner of the element) And moving mouse to that point. If you see, the mouse pointer isn't moved to the element's point rather it's moved little above of the element. This makes me to guess that `getLocation()` returns point of element with respective to desktop's screen resolution. **Please carefully observe the mouse pointer before and after**

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DragAndDropUsingRobot {
    WebDriver driver = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDragAndDrop() throws AWTException, InterruptedException{
        WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id("div1")); 

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        robot.mouseMove(source.getLocation().getX(), source.getLocation().getY());

        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Location (in python) refers to the location of the **top left corner** of an element area in the current [renderable canvas](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location). If you add the element's height and width to that, you get the bottom right corner of the element.

Also I believe the value is **scaled** - at least in Chrome's case, because it can contain float values, e.g.:

```
'location': {'y': 6825, 'x': 519.5}, 'size': {'width': 476, 'height': 16}
```

It can't be the desktop position, because it can return values larger than the desktop resolution. If you wish to have a desktop position, [location_once_scrolled_into_view](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location) is probably at least pretty close, but I haven't worked with it yet: It tells us

> where on the screen an element is so that we can click it. This method
>   should cause the element to be scrolled into view.

At least in python, it's an element property and not a method, and doesn't scroll an element into view AFAIK.